# How-to build a view in winamp where every artist that only has 1 song is excluded?

Tags: audio, mp3

I have tried to use the edit view feature in winamp.

I edit the current audio view and add a filter saying tracks not equal 1.

However, no matter what I do I can't seem to make it work.

What I'm after:

I want to create a view where I only see artists that I have more than one song of.

- I do not want to change attributes on the files.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I think it is not possible in current versions of Winamp. That filter that you have been setting (tracks > 1) compares with a field "Track #" in the ID3 tag of a file, not with a number of tracks of a specific artist.

> TRACKNO: Track number of file
>   
> TRACKS: Total number of tracks on the disc

In example, if your "Track #" field in the ID3 tag contains "1/20", then TRACKNO = 1 and TRACKS = 20.

Comment: Even if it was'nt the answer I was looking for, thank you. =)